# Qual è il significato di "fermo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idioms

Questo brano appartiene al racconto *L'inseguimento* di Italo Calvino (il corsivo è mio):

> Ora che abbiamo abolito il concetto di spazio (penso che anche il mio inseguitore in quest'attesa sia giunto alle mie stesse conclusioni) e che il concetto di moto non implica più la continuità del passaggio d'un corpo attraverso una serie di punti ma soltanto scambi discontinui e irregolari di corpi che occupano questo o quel punto, forse riuscirò ad accettare con meno impazienza la lentezza della coda, perché quello che conta è lo spazio relativo che si definisce e si trasforma intorno alla mia macchina come intorno a ogni altra macchina della coda. Insomma ogni macchina si trova al centro d'un sistema di relazioni che in pratica equivale a un altro, cioè le macchine sono intercambiabili tra loro, dico le macchine ognuna col suo guidatore dentro; ogni automobilista potrebbe benissimo scambiarsi di posto con un altro automobilista, anch'io con i miei vicini e il mio inseguitore con i suoi.
>
> In questi scambi di posizione si possono individuare localmente delle direzioni privilegiate: per esempio il senso di marcia della nostra colonna, il quale anche se non implica che in realtà si stia marciando, esclude però che si possa marciare nella direzione opposta. Per noi due, poi, quella dell'inseguimento è una direzione privilegiata, difatti il solo scambio di posizioni che non può avvenire è quello tra noi due, e qualsiasi altro scambio che sia in contraddizione col nostro inseguimento. Ciò dimostra che in questo mondo di apparenze intercambiabili il rapporto inseguitore-inseguito continua ad essere l'unica realtà a cui ci possiamo attenere.
>
> Il punto è questo: se ogni macchina - *fermo* restando il senso di marcia e il senso d'inseguimento - equivale a ogni altra macchina, le proprietà d'una qualsiasi macchina possono essere attribuite anche alle altre.

Non capisco l'uso né il significato del vocabolo "fermo" che se ne fa nell'ultima frase. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Il dubbio può venire, visto che il brano parla di *moto*; ma non ha nulla a che fare con il moto: *fermo restando* è una frase idiomatica. E lo trovo piuttosto brutto proprio per via del contesto.

Comment: puoi aggiungere il seguito? grazie.

Comment: @mario: Adesso non ho il libro con me perché è da una biblioteca, ma forse puoi leggerlo qui: https://books.google.es/books?id=W1cZAaRHpLsC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: No, Google non mi mostra proprio quelle due pagine. Comunque, sospetto che ci sia un gioco tra il movimento degli autoveicoli, e quello del pensiero che cerca di formulare alcune proprietà del movimento dei primi. Il 'fermo' di cui chiedi credo riguardi il tener fermi degli assunti in un ragionamento in cui si vagliano, e quindi si 'muovono', più ipotesi alternative. Mi procuro il libro e controllo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Fermo restando (che)](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/fermo_1.shtml)*** è un modo di dire che significa:

> - stabilito che

([Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/fermo_1.shtml))

> - restando stabilito che

([Hoepli](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/F/fermo.aspx?query=fermo))

Si tratta di un modo di dire molto comune usato per introdurre un presupposto, un assunto, un'ipotesi fissa sui cui basare i successivi ragionamenti

Nel contesto che proponi, viene usato nel senso di "a parte, escludendo" (il senso di marcia e il senso di inseguimento) ossia,     "fermo restando quanto detto" (in relazione al senso di marcia e di inseguimento), se ogni macchina equivale a ogni altra macchina....

Comment: Ho inserito un brano più ampio, così forse si capisce meglio il senso della frase con questo modo di dire.

Comment: Il contesto del brano è questo. Il narratore è in un ingorgo di traffico in cui tutte le macchine hanno lo stesso senso di marcia ed è impossibile cambiare senso. C'è una macchina che lo sta inseguendo, anche questa intrappolata nell'ingorgo, il cui occupante vuole ammazzare il narratore. Neanche il senso dell'inseguimento si può cambiare perché allora la situazione sarebbe assurda (l'inseguito inseguirebbe l'inseguitore).

Comment: Veramente "fermo restando" ha a volte il significato di "a parte, escludendo"? Non riesco a capire se il significato è quello che tu dici o se invece sarebbe "una volta stabiliti il senso di marcia e il senso d'inseguimento" (che non possono essere diversi da quelli che sono).

Comment: "*Fermo  restando* quanto detto" (in relazione al senso di marcia e di inseguimento), se ogni macchina equivale a ogni altra macchina....

Comment: D'accordo: "fermo restando quanto detto in relazione al senso di marcia e al senso di inseguimento", cioè, "restando stabilito quanto detto in relazione al senso di marcia e al senso di inseguimento". Quello che non capisco è che questo significhi "a parte, escludendo il senso di marcia e il senso di inseguimento".

Comment: "Fermo restando" ha in se il significato di qualcosa che rimane fisso come concetto e che quindi si può  , per così dire, escludere dal ragionamento.

Comment: Non riesco a vedere che l'ultima frase del brano significhi "restando stabilito che il senso di marcia e il senso di inseguimento sono diversi, ..." che è quello che mi sembra capire dalla tua risposta.

Answer (score 3):

"Fermo restando" è una forma idiomatica.

Nello specifico caso vuol dire "fissato/determinato" o "stabilito".

Uso degli esempi per far capire meglio.

Frase in esame:

> *fermo restando* il senso **di marcia** e il senso **d'inseguimento**

Esempio con "fissato":

> *fissato* il senso **di marcia** e il senso **d'inseguimento**

Esempio con "stabilito":

> *stabilito* il senso **di marcia** e il senso **d'inseguimento**

Un'altra sostituzione potrebbe essere "considerando un determinato (che è fissato, stabilito, o considerato in un solo modo) senso di marcia e senso d'inseguimento".

"Fermo restando" --> spezzando l'espressione e analizzandola singolarmente:

-**Fermo:** come sinonimi si può usare, fissato, determinato, definito.

-**Restando:** viene tralasciato, riscrivendo la frase senza l'espressione. Serve a specificare insieme a "fermo", che mantenendo una certa considerazione, si deve continuare il ragionamento non considerando entrambe le opzioni in questo caso i "sensi di marcia" e "d'inseguimento", ma considerandone soltanto un'opzione, ovvero un singolo "senso di marcia" e "d'inseguimento".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Zeus, e grazie della risposta!